# Can I carry a powerbank of 10000 mAh capacity in a Turkish Airlines flight to Germany?

Tags: luggage, germany, hand-luggage, turkish-airlines

I'm travelling to **Germany** from **Bangladesh** (transit at **Istanbul**) on a Turkish Airlines flight. I wonder if I can carry a powerbank of **10000mAH** in cabin luggage.

Comment: Very likely, but the limits are set in Wh (energy capacity), not Ah (electrical charge capacity). Most airlines and national regulation bodies do not allow lithium batteries with more than 100Wh capacity in hand luggage. The rating of power banks in mAh or Ah is often just meaningless and/or exaggerated marketing gibberish.

Comment: https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-us/any-questions/restrictions/ also says 100Wh is the limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a typical 3.7V Lithium-ion battery voltage, 10Ah is 37Wh (watts are volts times amperes), which is well under the 100Wh limit. Even if you assume it's 10,000mAh at the 5V output (and for not-so-subtle marketing reasons the makers don't tend to do that- the voltage should be indicated on the label) it's still 50Wh, which is half the limit. But it won't be, it will be no more than 37 and if it's an off-brand possibly substantially less- but **the label is what matters here**, not reality.

[Huawei](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/accessories/20000-powerbank/) and other quality brand-name makers offer 20Ah power banks which can be brought aboard (74Wh).

You specifically say cabin luggage, which is fine, but for anyone else reading this question, a reminder never to put lithium batteries or devices containing lithium batteries into checked bags, and that counts double for dodgy power banks from unknown makers.

Comment: so https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B081K8D371/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 is allowed in the cabin bag?

Comment: @Gadelkareem Yes, and Xiaomi is certainly a reputable brand name. For whatever reason it's difficult to buy those in North America.